# Python stops binary reading of file after getting byte 0xa or 0xd

Tags: python-3.x, binaryfiles, eof, binary-data, ubuntu-18.04

I want to read some binary file. It is a big file so i use maximalOffset variable to stop reading after getting to it. But reading is always ends at one offset - 8199. The last byte i get is 0xa. In xxd it is the part of byte 0a0d.

I am using Ubuntu 18 and Python 3.

I found some info about 0x1A in Windows (it's EOF symbol or something) but the solution was to use binary reading and 0xA is not 0x1A...

```
maximalOffsetString = "2070"
maximalOffset=int(maximalOffsetString,16)
offset=-16 # first 16 bytes must be on 0x0 offset
line = [ ]

pagefile = open("./pagefile", "rb")
for bytes in pagefile:
    for byte in bytes:
        if maximalOffset==offset: break
        if len(line) == 16:
            print(hex(offset))
            print(str(offset)+" : "+str(maximalOffset))
            print(line)
            del line[:]
        line.append(hex(byte))
        offset=offset+1
    break
pagefile.close()

# here i see what was the last symbols in array:
print(hex(offset))
print(str(offset)+" : "+str(maximalOffset))
print(line)
```

Output:

```
0x2007
8199 : 8304
['0xf0', '0xa9', '0xc', '0x7', '0x71', '0xc0', '0xa']
```

as you can see, my maximalOffset is 8304 but the reading stops at 8199. In xxd this line is:

00002010: f0a9 0c07 71c0 0a0d 0000 006c 0105 5c00

All file before this is only zeros. After 0x2000 there are random bytes.

```
00001fb0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001fc0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001fd0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001fe0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001ff0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00002000: 0104 0000 6f01 005c 0094 008c e026 6469  ....o..\.....&di
00002010: f0a9 0c07 71c0 0a0d 0000 006c 0105 5c00  ....q......l..\.
00002020: 9500 8c20 b800 8040 0001 10ab 0c07 4230  ... ...@......B0
00002030: 0dba 0069 010a 5c00 9600 8ce8 b800 38a7  ...i..\.......8.
00002040: 0c07 fbd0 7b01 6601 0f5c 0097 0008 0020  ....{.f..\..... 
00002050: 208c f8b8 0090 940d 0724 0000 7a01 6301   ........$..z.c.
00002060: 0c5c 0098 008c 0027 6469 9892 0d07 f2b9  .\.....'di......
00002070: 0009 0080 4100 4100 6001 115c 0099 008c  ....A.A.`..\....
00002080: 08b8 0020 0d0e 072b 7c01 7d01 165c 009a  ... ...+|.}..\..
00002090: 008c 10b8 0028 a20c 0727 bc00 8100 4200  .....(...'....B.
000020a0: 7a01 1b5c 009b 008c 18b9 009f 0d07 29bc  z..\..........).
000020b0: 0077 0118 5c00 9c00 8c98 b803 6091 0d07  .w..\.......`...
000020c0: 06b0 3b05 4000 0103 7401 1d5c 009d 7801  ..;.@...t..\..x.
000020d0: b800 208f 0d07 10f0 097a 0471 0122 5c00  .. ......z.q."\.
```

Comment: Hello, you'd need to provide us with the binary file too for us to fully understand your problem.

Comment: It is a big pagefile.sys from Windows (8 GB). I can provide the part i can't get over.

Comment: Oh, well in that case, never mind :/

Comment: So reading stops at `00002010` , which line do you want it to stop on?

Comment: "but the reading stops at 8199" - what is 8199? line number? byte number? byte?

Comment: maximalOffsetString = "2070" - 0x2070 offset in hex. 8199 is decimal for 0x2007. It's amount of processed bytes. Actually i can change this to any bigger offsets, it will stop on 0x2007.

Comment: It works well with file filled with zeros, for example. There is no problem with memory of something, i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are breaking the outer for loop before reading is finished, remove `break` at the bottom of the outer for loop.

```
...

for bytes in pagefile:
    for byte in bytes:

        ...

        line.append(hex(byte))
        offset=offset+1
    break # <- Remove this
pagefile.close()

...
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I changed it to "if maximalOffset==offset: break" to actually break the loop. But now i completely lost: i thought that "bytes in pagefile" was all the bytes from file and loop for byte will end only when all bytes processed. Any idea why there is several "bytes" in one binary file?

Comment: No problem :) and welcome to StackOverflow. There are several bytes in one binary file because an 8GB file is too much for the system to read all in one go, so it will read a section of the file to memory, and allow you to process it (inner for loop) and then it will read the next section overwriting the previous section and so on. This ensures that only the minimum amount of strain is put on memory.

Comment: You can find out more about this by researching `Buffer`. The process described in the comment above isn't limited to Python, it applies to many different areas in computer science.